# задача ввести в поле число с плавающей точкой и при нажатии на кнопку получить число которое идёт после точки (на пример: от 48.55 получить 0.55)

Tags: javascript

```js
function sec() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + (x / 60) +' min.'
}
function dollar() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + (x / 479.75)+' $'
}
function num1() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + (Math.floor(x))
}
function num2() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = ' + x
}
function num3() {
    let x = +numbers.value
    result.innerHTML = 'result is = '+ x
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin: auto">
   <input id="numbers">
   <br>
   <br>
   <button onclick="sec()">конвертировать в минуты</button>
   <button onclick="dollar()">конвертировать в доллары</button>
   <button onclick="num1()">целое число</button>
   <button onclick="num2()">добная часть числа</button>
   <button onclick="num3()">сумма цифр четырехзначного числа
</button>
   <br>
   <h1 id="result"></h1>
   </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const num = 123.34;
console.log(num.toString().split('.')[1]);
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста этот код, что есть что?

Comment: число приводим к строке, потом строку разбиваем по точке и берем второй элемент